# Looping a function in CMD

Tags: python, loops, cmd

How can I loop the following to give me the values of sigma z for h where h is

```
h = np.array[0,3,0.1]
```

Instead of having to do the function over and over with h =1, h = 2... and so on 30 times

Here I just have what each value represents in case anyone is a bit confused
[image]

Here is the part I need to loop 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely clear on the use case here. If you will always be doing the [0,3,0.1] range with a step of .1, maybe you don't have to expose **--h** to a user.

Assuming your function takes h and all the other values are default:

```
h = np.arange([0,3,0.1]) # I think you meant 'arange()' instead of 'array()' above

for impurity_val in h:
    calculate_hamiltonian(h)
```

Otherwise, you can write a python script to generate a string by looping through the vals. The string will chain the commands, for example:

```
python ThreeSpinDriving.py --h 0 && ThreeSpinDriving --h 1 && ThreeSpinDriving -h 3
```

Comment: I did indeed mean arange() thank you! I'm trying to do it in the command line without modifying the code

Comment: Thanks think that will do the job

Comment: Can you give me an upvote please I'm not sure why I've been downvoted above